# Disable layout in a view in joomla

Tags: ajax, joomla

It is possible to disable the layout (template) for a view in Joomla.

I'm loading a table using Ajax and I only want to load the table with out the template.

I discover the function `setLayout` but i don't know if exists a value to disable the template(layout).

Comment: There are several ways to do this depending on the version of Joomla! and the setup of your component/module. Can you give more details e.g. Joomla! version are you loading the table from a component or module or some other mechanism...

Comment: Are you trying to get just JSON data for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading the results using Ajax, you can stop loading template by adding the below code after echoing the output you need.

Ex:

```
echo YOUR TABLE OUTPUT HERE
jexit();
```

Now it will not render your template anymore.